# Is it possible for an external application to access an attribute in Magento

Tags: magento, attributes, external

Alright, I want to make an attribute in Magento and I wanted to know if it is possible for an external application to access an attribute.
We want an EAN code to show up on our website. Is this only possible with an attribute or is there another way?
In the future we also want to use more external applications to access this attribute.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is possible for an attribute to access an external application". The sentence is pretty vague to me.

Comment: As the attribute exists as an entry in a table in Magento's database, are you expecting the attribute to be populated from an external program or are you expecting to modify Magento to pull that attribute's information from another source? The former can be done by imports or API, the second will take some codesmithing.